Why does the gc log in my java example output this?
//-XX:+PrintGCDetails -Xms20m -Xmx20m -Xmn10m -XX:SurvivorRatio=8
public class EdenTest {
    private static final int _1MB = 1024 * 1024;
    static byte[] allocation1, allocation2, allocation3, allocation4;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        allocation1 = new byte[2 * _1MB];
        allocation2 = new byte[2 * _1MB];
        allocation3 = new byte[2 * _1MB];
        allocation4 = new byte[4 * _1MB];
    }
}


According to the theory, allocation1, allocation2, and allocation3 enter the Eden area first. Then when allocation4 prepares the Eden area, there is insufficient memory, and there is not enough space in s0 and s1. Will the jvm put allocation1, allocation2, and allocation3 into the Old area, and then put allocation4 into the Eden area? In this way, the size of the Old area should be around 6M. The size of the Eden area is around 4M. The s0 and s1 areas should be empty, but my output is as follows?
[GC (Allocation Failure) [PSYoungGen: 6267K->872K(9216K)] 6267K->4976K(19456K), 0.0014582 secs] [Times: user=0.00 sys=0.00, real=0.00 secs] 
Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 9216K, used 7337K [0x00000000ff600000, 0x0000000100000000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 8192K, 78% used [0x00000000ff600000,0x00000000ffc50650,0x00000000ffe00000)
  from space 1024K, 85% used [0x00000000ffe00000,0x00000000ffeda020,0x00000000fff00000)
  to   space 1024K, 0% used [0x00000000fff00000,0x00000000fff00000,0x0000000100000000)
 ParOldGen       total 10240K, used 4104K [0x00000000fec00000, 0x00000000ff600000, 0x00000000ff600000)
  object space 10240K, 40% used [0x00000000fec00000,0x00000000ff002020,0x00000000ff600000)
 Metaspace       used 3334K, capacity 4496K, committed 4864K, reserved 1056768K
  class space    used 363K, capacity 388K, committed 512K, reserved 1048576K

Why is the output inconsistent with the theoretical result?

Your theory does not count objects that are already in the heap when main method starts, i.e. objects allocated during the VM bootstrap.

Aren’t objects of that size allocated directly into the Old Gen anyway? I don’t remember the threshold…
